# How to create the notification icon in the right side of the statusbar on blackberry?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, statusbar

I am able to create the notification icon in the statusbar using ApplicationIndicator class. It shows up in the middle of the screen on the indicator area. How do I create the icon in the right side of the status bar near to the wi-fi icon. Is there any way I can tell the postion where to create the notification icon in the status bar.

---

Thank you. Is it possible to create an another icon like existing Battery meter, signal strength, bluetooth and wi-fi icons with out using the ApplicationIndicator class?

Does RIMM allow to create such an icon in that indicator icon area?

Answer (score 4):

I believe that is dependent on the the theme that the blackberry is using.

Comment: +1 agree, there is no way to set indicator position, it's defined by theme.